# Is glDeleteBuffers/glGenBuffers needed if I want to resize the buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl

Firstly the VBO was initialized like below:

```cpp
GLuint vertex_buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data_size_in_bytes, data_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

`data_vertices` store some points data, then I push back another points into it and `data_vertices` will be resized (larger).

If `glDeleteBuffers`/`glGenBuffers` needed to be called again or only just `glBindBuffer` the new data?

```cpp
GLuint vertex_buffer;
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer); // is this necessary?
glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer); // is this necessary?
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, new_data_size_in_bytes, new_data_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Now I did not call `glDeleteBuffers`/`glGenBuffers` in every update frame, and on some computers the points maybe disappear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`glGenBuffers`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml) doesn't generate an object, but just generate respectively reserves buffer object names.
[`glBufferData`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) creates and initializes a buffer object's data store. When creating the new data storage any pre-existing data storage will be deleted.
[`glDeleteBuffers`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDeleteBuffers.xhtml) deletes the buffer object and makes its name unused again.

To answer your question, as long as you do not delete the buffer with `glDeleteBuffers`, you do not need to create a new buffer name with `glGenBuffers`. You can use an existing buffer name to create a new buffer object data storage with `glBufferData`. If there is already a data storage it is deleted.

However, you should try not to recreate the data store as this is a very time-consuming process. You should prefer to create a data store with the maximum required size and update only the data in the existing data store with [`glBufferSubData`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml). Updating the data in an existing data store is faster than creating an entirely new one.

Comment: @wayright *"When creating the new data storage any pre-existing data storage will be deleted."*